# Obtaining a pointer to Lua object instance in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, lua, luabind

I am using [Luabind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabind/) to expose a base class from C++ to Lua from which I can [derive classes in Lua](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#deriving-in-lua). This part works correctly and I am able to call C++ methods from my derived class in Lua.

Now what I want to do is obtain a pointer to the Lua-based instance in my C++ program.

**C++ -> Binding**

```
class Enemy {
private:
  std::string name;

public:
  Enemy(const std::string& n) 
    : name(n) { 
  }

  const std::string& getName() const { 
    return name; 
  }

  void setName(const std::string& n) { 
    name = n; 
  }

  virtual void update() { 
    std::cout << "Enemy::update() called.\n"; 
  }
};

class EnemyWrapper : public Enemy, public luabind::wrap_base {
public:
  EnemyWrapper(const std::string& n) 
    : Enemy(n) { 
  }

  virtual void update() { 
    call<void>("update"); 
  }

  static void default_update(Enemy* ptr) {
    ptr->Enemy::update();
  }

};

// Now I bind the class as such:
module(L)
[
class_<Enemy, EnemyWrapper>("Enemy")
  .def(constructor<const std::string&, int>())
    .property("name", &Enemy::getName, &Enemy::setName)
    .def("update", &Enemy::update, &EnemyWrapper::default_update)
];
```

**Lua-based Derived Class**

```
class 'Zombie' (Enemy)

function Zombie:__init(name)
    Enemy.__init(self, name)
end

function Zombie:update()
    print('Zombie:update() called.')
end
```

Now let's say I have the following object created from Lua:

```
a = Zombie('example zombie', 1)
```

How can I get a reference of that object as a pointer to the base class in C++?

Comment: My previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416797/reference-to-lua-function-in-c-c . You have to register the object with the Lua Registry (in the native side)

Comment: See my answer to jameszhao00's question. You use the Lua Registry to get an integer value that can refer to a specific Lua object. That integer value is analogous to a pointer, and can be used to retrieve the object later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in Lua you do

```
zombie = Zombie('example zombie', 1)
```

then you can get the value of the zombie like this:

```
object_cast<Enemy*>(globals(L)["zombie"]);
```

(`object_cast` and `globals` are members of the luabind namespace, `L` is your Lua state)
This assumes you know the names of the variables you create in Lua.

You can always call a C++ method from Lua that takes a pointer to Enemy:

```
void AddEnemy(Enemy* enemy) { /* ... */ }
//...
module(L) [ def("AddEnemy", &AddEnemy) ]
```

and call it from Lua

```
a = Zombie("zombie", 1);
AddEnemy(a)
```

Be aware that if you do

```
AddEnemy(Zombie("temp zombie", 1));
```

Lua will delete the "temp zombie" after the method call and invalidate any pointers to the object.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Thanks also for the tip about the "temp zombie". Can this garbage collecting be worked around by using smart/shared pointers?

Comment: @sbk, I cleaned up the formatting. SO's Markdown apparently doesn't like code paragraphs near bullet lists, so I dropped the bullets in favor of having the code be clear. I put the Lua code in `<pre>` tags without indent for consistency with the C++ code.