# How do you pass a Lua Function to a C Function and execute the Lua Function Several Times?

Tags: function, lua, stack, push, arguments

What I want to do is create a function that will iterate through some objects and call a function for each function. I'm using BlitzMax, not C, but that is besides the point because it has a full wrapper of Lua's C functions. Lua has a lua_pushcfunction() command, but where's it's lua_pushfunction() command? It is very easy to call functions that have a name, but how do you call a function that was passed as a argument?

Something like:

```
ForEach( PlanetList, function (planet)
    if(planet.exists == true) then
        Planet_Count = Planet_Count + 1
    end
end )
```

Usually you just say "lua_getglobal(L,name)" and it puts the lua function nicely on the stack, but how do you get it from an argument?

**EDIT**

I went back and and actually tried using `luaL_ref()` from [this question I found earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416797/reference-to-lua-function-in-c-c). What I am doing is using luaL_ref() to pop the function value from the top of the stack and put it into a temporary register, I used the value returned from `luaL_ref()` to use `lua_rawgeti()` for each of the items in the list. And then used `luaL_unref()` after the list was finished to release that register.

Comment: Please extract your solution to an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same question since I'm new to Lua myself. Since, in my opinion, there was no satisfactory answer I figured I would write one, even though this question may not ever be closed. Hopefully this will help some else in this situation.

**main.c**

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

/* this keeps our Lua reference to the Lua function */
int callback_reference = 0;

/* this is called by Lua to register its function */
int lua_registerCallback( lua_State *L ) {

  /* store the reference to the Lua function in a variable to be used later */
  callback_reference = luaL_ref( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX );

  return 0;
}

/* calls our Lua callback function and resets the callback reference */
void call_callback( lua_State *L ) {

  /* push the callback onto the stack using the Lua reference we */
  /*  stored in the registry */
  lua_rawgeti( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, callback_reference );

  /* duplicate the value on the stack */
  /* NOTE: This is unnecessary, but it shows how you keep the */
  /*  callback for later */
  lua_pushvalue( L, 1 );

  /* call the callback */
  /* NOTE: This is using the one we duplicated with lua_pushvalue */
  if ( 0 != lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 ) ) {
    printf("Failed to call the callback!\n %s\n", lua_tostring( L, -1 ) );
    return;
  }

  /* get a new reference to the Lua function and store it again */
  /* NOTE: This is only used in conjunction with the lua_pushvalue */
  /*  above and can be removed if you remove that */
  callback_reference = luaL_ref( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX );
}

int main( void ) {

  /* set up Lua */
  lua_State *L = lua_open();
  luaL_openlibs( L );

  /* register the lua_registerCallback function as */
  /*  "RegisterCallback" so it can be called by Lua */
  lua_pushcfunction( L, lua_registerCallback );
  lua_setglobal( L, "RegisterCallback" );

  /* run our Lua file */
  if ( 0 != luaL_dofile( L, "callback.lua" ) ) {
    printf("Failed to load calback.lua!\n %s",
      lua_tostring( L, -1 ) );
    lua_close( L );
    return 1;
  }

  /* call the callback */
  call_callback( L );

  /* call the callback again if you want (because we restored */
  /*  the Lua function reference) */
  call_callback( L );

  /* remove the reference to the callback */
  /* NOTE: This is also unnecessary if you didn't re-add the */
  /*  function to the registry */
  luaL_unref( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, callback_reference );

  /* uninitialize Lua */
  lua_close( L );

  return 0;
}
```

**callback.lua**

```
function MyCallback()
  print("Hello World!")
end

RegisterCallback( MyCallback )
```

Comment: in my test, you need remove `lua_pushvalue( L, 1 );` to get this code work, or you may get `Failed to call the callback!` error

Comment: after more test, I found this implement not work in async program, because there is no way to get a valid `lua_State` when you call callback.I also tried save a `lua_State` but got access violation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lua_pushvalue` once you have the function on the stack to duplicate it.

Update:  You will need to call lua_pushvalue() each time you want to call the function as actually calling the function with lua_pcall() or lua_call() will pop the function from the stack.

Comment: That worked, but only for the first one loop through. :S I think I found my answer tho, I'll update the first post.