# Passing Lua function to C++

Tags: c++, lua

I am making a GUI in C++.

I want a Lua script to register a Lua function with C++, so that when a button click is handled by C++, C++ will call a registered Lua function.

I have used the following SO post as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928973/how-do-you-pass-a-lua-function-to-a-c-function-and-execute-the-lua-function-seve

For some reason, with my changes, it is not working.

This is my Lua code:

```
-- this is button.setClickEvent
function self.setClickEvent(eventFunction)
    uiButtonSetClickEvent(self.id, eventFunction)
end
```

---

```
function buttonClick()
    print("yay it worked!")
end

button.setClickEvent(buttonClick)
```

Here is the C++ code

```
static int lua_uiButtonSetClickEvent(lua_State *L)
{
    int argumentsCount = lua_gettop(L);
    int argumentsMin = 2;
    if(argumentsCount < argumentsMin)
        cout << "Error at uiButtonSetClickEvent, incorrect number of arguments" << endl;

    double buttonId = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    int event = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    long i = uiButtonGetIndex(buttonId);
    if(i != -1)
    {
        cout << "!!! Storing lua function reference" << endl;
        uiButtons[i].luaClickEvent = event;
        uiButtonSetClickEvent(buttonId, lua_uiButtonCallClickEvent);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void uiButtonSetClickEvent(double buttonId, void (&event)(double))
{
    long i = uiButtonGetIndex(buttonId);
    if(i != -1)
        uiButtons[i].clickEvent = event;
}

static void lua_uiButtonCallClickEvent(double buttonId)
{
    long i = uiButtonGetIndex(buttonId);
    if(i != -1)
    {
          lua_rawgeti( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, uiButtons[i].luaClickEvent);

          if ( 0 != lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 ) ) {
            printf("Failed to call the callback!\n %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
            return;
          }

          uiButtons[i].luaClickEvent = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    }
}
```

Everything happens as expected, up until the point at which

The result is a segmentation fault in `lua_uiButtonCallClickEvent` at the following line:

```
lua_rawgeti( L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, uiButtons[i].luaClickEvent);
```

The only difference I notice between the guide on SO and my implementation is that not only pass the Lua function to C++, but also a `buttonId`.

I do not know if the parameter offset is causing the problem or not.

The integer that references the Lua function is 3.

I have tried researching the Lua reference manual but have not been successful.

I believe the fix I am looking for is trivial, and I hope that you can help.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Maybe your Lua stack is already destroyed when calling `lua_rawgeti`? **LUA_REGISTRYINDEX** won't become invalid and an invalid index just results in **nil** pushed onto the stack (so **lua_pcall** should cause the crash).

Comment: I can't output to the console after lua_rawgeti because of the segfault so it isnt lua_pcall, however it is not just lua_rawgeti, if I try to use any lua_* function when uiButtonCallClickEvent is called through its pointer, lua falls flat on its face with the segfault, so it seems something has gone wrong before I call the c++ function through its pointer. I am using the GLFW library, and this chain of events stems from a glfw callback for the mouse button :'( glfw may be the problem. It's certainly nothing to do with having an extra parameter as I have tested my code without glfw and it works

Comment: So you are correct, the lua stack seems to already be inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lua_close(L) was called too early, which destroyed the lua stack.